# mail() error in PHP: Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

Tags: php, email, mime

I've ran into some problems with mail() in PHP. When sending my mail, it tells me the headers contains malformatted newlines. [I've read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header), and it didn't solve my problem. I'm also aware that I can't use `\r\r`, `\r\0`, `\r\n\r\n`, `\n\n`, or `\n\0`, which I have not. But where's the problem then? I can't figure out. Thanks for your time.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file_size = filesize($filename);
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)
}

mail_attachment("invoice/0.pdf", "customer@customer.com", "noreply@mattronic.dk", "Mattronic", "reply@mattronic.dk", "Invoice", "Describing text");
```

Comment: question which is linked by your contains answer

Comment: @Lashlane, As mentioned above, the link did NOT fix my problem

Comment: `Use additional_headers for headers only. Email message (multipart or not, with ir without attachments, etc) belongs in message argument, not in headers.` you ARE using headers for content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with PHP mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional\_header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to send message body as headers, as mentioned in the comments to your question.

Trying to send MIME mail attachments via `mail()` is probably considered torture in some countries. There are plenty of libraries to do this for you, I use the [PEAR Mail_Mime package](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    include("Mail.php");
    include("Mail/mime.php");
    $headers = [
        "To"=>$mailto,
        "From"=>"$from_name <$from_mail>",
        "Reply-To"=>$replyto
        "Subject"=>$subject,
        "Date"=>date(DATE_RFC822),
    ];
    $msg = new Mail_mime();
    $mail =& Mail::factory("smtp");
    $msg->setTXTBody($message);
    $msg->addAttachment(file_get_contents($filename), "application/pdf", basename($filename), false);
    $body = $msg->get();
    $headers = $msg->headers($headers);
    $mail->send($email_address, $headers, $body);
}
```