# PHP mail() header attachment first line received as blank (file gets corrupted)

Tags: php, email, attachment

Currently moving a website from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.6 web server.

Headers sent out:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=93ef188fcef0a7216f79ab8c153cbdd8
--93ef188fcef0a7216f79ab8c153cbdd8
Content-Type:image/png; name="marker_default.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="marker_default.png"
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAiCAMAAABodAmPAAAByFBMVEUAAACdPTedPTehQDqiQDqh
PzmdPTedPTedPTedPTedPTejQTudPTedPTedPTedPTedPTeoRD2gPzmyTUadPTedPTedPTedPTew
S0SgPzmdPTedPTedPTexS0SdPTegPzmhQDqdPTevS0SuSkSiQDqdPTefPzigPzmhQDmiQDquR0Gw
S0ShQDmdPTehPzmdPTefPzihQDm9UUmwSUGdPTedPTe2TES5TkavS0TJV06dPTeiQDqgPznZYFav
SEGhQDqySUK4TUW9UEjBUkqpRT7IVk3EVEuuSEHFVEzIVk3PWlGdPTe4TUWdPTedPTedPTe1TESd
PTedPTf1d21/QDurRj/CVk7lc2l/QDrsdmy7TkfQYlr1f3XHV07JWVHCVU3ld23CVEt/QTyzTEX/
dmqzS0QqFhSxSEH/eGysSEG4TUbsc2n/d2vUXVSePTe+UEgqFRT/f3T/eW3/fHH1fXMqFRP0f3T/
fHD/fnPsd270f3X/h33QYFfHWFDHXFX1f3Z/Qjz1fHP/hHn/gXfrd23/h3z/gXb/gHWuSkQAAAD/
g3ijQDr/e2//fXKtSEH/hnz/gnf0fnSvS0T/eW7/hHr/hXv/em7GXFROeYTzAAAAUnRSTlMAnx/w
4PonMmOSGYiOWQmMIGLp/AwbWn/40qF9Ivig1O8h/PnVJOvy+/2n/O8d/Qjq/ivNCoHdcvmTFP7x
MfDW98jWn7qydMZ0WWUlMhYVB7YGA1O5QAAAAUpJREFUeF5lymOXK1EUhOEdm0PbNq5t7tg2x7Z1
jb8753TUST+far2rIIcvlbU2yqR8KJme6cP5Xxdd+KBOXWgdj3Fvf5vY+o/d+XNPb5XzNG+taryZ
NnXbkPN70c/OhjES63DzL8sJNgHI9Y6VPyyHDr0cVGg7IrwH4fCBly4bqkDTckX5Lwk/M+s1wIv9
oLI0ZpkZ4wHv2zGVi8wkURk4o4w0GpkZUEItJs4Ji3V11WqhK4G1UNO+s1hmR1ADoEDDBosBFQBQ
LTSzo1lYDYRY4Lkt8gyLgSER7S7n7YokkKdD9zrDjTooehG6YYReQ4m23/WPcA1ogWXQ9JswfQG2
kVHf0pJvYhLKTMWj0fgslJvDZBIXKuK9+8Hg9UOo8CiVegKVnmYyzzjxud3+khNfRSJvOPEt4jtO
fI/4gRM/In7ixM/p9NfCvgOq9p5F2Ax/VwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
--93ef188fcef0a7216f79ab8c153cbdd8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
blah1
blah2
--4232d7272cf9b15a4a438f88a11b6905--
```

Headers received in hotmail:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=4232d7272cf9b15a4a438f88a11b6905
Return-Path: *********
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 26 Nov 2015 12:41:08.0908 (UTC) FILETIME=[B96B96C0:01D12847]

--4232d7272cf9b15a4a438f88a11b6905
Content-Type:image/png; name="marker_default.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="marker_default.png"
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--4232d7272cf9b15a4a438f88a11b6905
Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
blah1
blah2
--4232d7272cf9b15a4a438f88a11b6905--
```

Line "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAiCAMAAABodAmPAAAByFBMVEUAAACdPTedPTehQDqiQDqh" is missing and can't figure out why. If the attachment has only 1 base64 line, then that gets deleted and file will be received as blank.

Before moving to new server, code had newline between file headers and base64 content, but PHP 5.6 new security update requires that header cannot contain any blank lines ([Error with PHP mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header))