# php mail() headers prevent email from sending

Tags: php, email, smtp, html-email, email-headers

I won't lie. I don't really understand some of the code I have used in the header for this mail function. I have been trying to fix it myself and some of the code is copied from other forum posts etc.

The `$email`, `$subject`, and `$msg` variables are all fine, and emails were sending when I tested them earlier with just these 3 vars. Then I added a header for the "From" section and the sender name was fixed (but emails went into my junk folder - annoying).

Now I am trying to add some html tags to the `$msg` and have used the last 2 lines on my `$header` variable as per other forum posts, but this has just stopped emails from getting sent at all. Please advise me on how to fix the issue.

```
$headers = "From: website <donotreply@website.com>" . PHP_EOL .
"BCC: customer1@hotmail.com" . PHP_EOL . 
"MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n" . PHP_EOL . 
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' \r\n";

$email = "SomeEmail@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Weekly Newsletter";
mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

Thanks guys I comment section for reminding me to post the error. It says:

Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /path/publishnewsletter.php on line 45

Comment: are you getting a error?

Comment: Please check Apache error.log, and mail log and post error?

Comment: I knew I forgot to add something to the question. Thank you - 
Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /path/publishnewsletter.php on line 45

Comment: you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header

Comment: `PHP_EOL` ... Don't use that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n" . PHP_EOL .` is too many newlines. Don’t use `PHP_EOL` at all; use `\r\n`, and only once.

You also have an extra single quote after `charset`.

```
$headers =
    "From: website <donotreply@website.com>\r\n" .
    "BCC: customer1@hotmail.com\r\n" . 
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

Answer (score -1):

**Look at this it might help**:

- Sanitize your headers. No multiple newlines in `additional_headers` argument. These count as "multiple or malformed newlines": `\r\r, \r\0, \r\n\r\n, \n\n, \n\0`.
- Use `additional_headers` for headers only. Email message (multipart or not, with ir without attachments, etc) belongs in `message` argument, not in headers.
- And DO NOT use `PHP_EOL`

PHP Security Bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68776
C Code diff how its fixed: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blobdiff;f=ext/standard/mail.c;h=448013a472a3466245e64b1cb37a9d1b0f7c007e;hp=1ebc8fecb7ef4c266a341cdc701f0686d6482242;hb=9d168b863e007c4e15ebe4d2eecabdf8b0582e30;hpb=eee8b6c33fc968ef8c496db8fb54e8c9d9d5a8f9

Comment: This is the right answer, but also: A SINGLE \n IS SUFFICIENT. There is no need for any \r whatsoever. FWIW, the mail command also generates a newline if you just have the next line of text on a new line in PHP, literally type your headers out with a return between the lines and without any \n linebreaks at all. It makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: “Use additional_headers for headers only. Email message (multipart or not, with ir without attachments, etc) belongs in message argument, not in headers.” Is there an indication of this in the question…?

Comment: sorry if i posted something worong @RyanO'Hara

Comment: @joshstrike: https://php.net/mail: “Multiple extra headers **should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n)**. … If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. … **This should be a last resort**, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.”