# multple file attachment in mail with php

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I have below code for mail attachment, but it is not working, dont know why it is happening..

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $subject, $message){    
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$uid}x"; 

    $header = "From: <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= nl2br($message)."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

    foreach($filename as $k=>$v){

        $file = $path.$v;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$v."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$v."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$mime_boundary."--"."\r\n";
    } 

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        //echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        return true;
    } else {
        //echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        return false;
    }
}
$path='upload/';
$send_email = mail_attachment($files, $path, $to, "roxmorphy26@gmail", $subject, $message);
//mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($send_email){ echo 'done';} else {echo 'not';}
```

but it gives error like -- Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

please help.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
define("LIBR", "\n"); // use a "\r\n" if you have problems
define("PRIORITY", 3); // 3 = normal, 2 = high, 4 = low
define("TRANS_ENC", "7bit");
define("ENCODING", "iso-8859-1");


class attach_mailer {

    var $from_name;
    var $from_mail;
    var $mail_to;
    var $mail_cc;
    var $mail_bcc;
    var $webmaster_email = "webmaster@yourdomain.com";

    var $mail_headers;
    var $mail_subject;
    var $text_body = "";
    var $html_body = "";

    var $valid_mail_adresses; // boolean is true if all mail(to) adresses are valid

    var $uid; // the unique value for the mail boundry
    var $alternative_uid; // the unique value for the mail boundry
    var $related_uid; // the unique value for the mail boundry

    var $html_images = array();
    var $att_files = array();

    var $msg = array();

    // functions inside this constructor
    // - validation of e-mail adresses
    // - setting mail variables
    // - setting boolean $valid_mail_adresses
    function attach_mailer($name = "", $from, $to, $cc = "", $bcc = "", $subject = "") {
        $this->valid_mail_adresses = true;
        if (!$this->check_mail_address($to)) {
            $this->msg[] = "Error, the \"mailto\" address is empty or not valid.";
            $this->valid_mail_adresses = false;
        } 
        if (!$this->check_mail_address($from)) {
            $this->msg[] = "Error, the \"from\" address is empty or not valid.";
            $this->valid_mail_adresses = false;
        } 
        if ($cc != "") {
            if (!$this->check_mail_address($cc)) {
                $this->msg[] = "Error, the \"Cc\" address is not valid.";
                $this->valid_mail_adresses = false;
            } 
        }
        if ($bcc != "") {
            if (!$this->check_mail_address($bcc)) {
                $this->msg[] = "Error, the \"Bcc\" address is not valid.";
                $this->valid_mail_adresses = false;
            } 
        }
        if ($this->valid_mail_adresses) {
            $this->from_name = $this->strip_line_breaks($name);
            $this->from_mail = $this->strip_line_breaks($from);
            $this->mail_to = $this->strip_line_breaks($to);
            $this->mail_cc = $this->strip_line_breaks($cc);
            $this->mail_bcc = $this->strip_line_breaks($bcc);
            $this->mail_subject = $this->strip_line_breaks($subject);
        } else {
            return;
        }       
    }
    function get_msg_str() {
        $messages = "";
        foreach($this->msg as $val) {
            $messages .= $val."<br />\n";
        }
        return $messages;           
    }
    // use this to prent formmail spamming
    function strip_line_breaks($val) {
        $val = preg_replace("/([\r\n])/", "", $val);
        return $val;
    }
    function check_mail_address($mail_address) {
        $pattern = "/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]*[0-9a-z]\.)+([a-z]{2,4})$/i";
        if (preg_match($pattern, $mail_address)) {
            if (function_exists("checkdnsrr")) {
                $parts = explode("@", $mail_address);
                if (checkdnsrr($parts[1], "MX")){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // on windows hosts is only a limited e-mail address validation possible
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function get_file_data($filepath) {
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            if (!$str = file_get_contents($filepath)) {
                $this->msg[] = "Error while opening attachment \"".basename($filepath)."\"";
            } else {
                return $str;
            }
        } else {
            $this->msg[] = "Error, the file \"".basename($filepath)."\" does not exist.";
            return;
        }
    }
    // use for $dispo "attachment" or "inline" (f.e. example images inside a html mail
    function add_attach_file($file, $encoding = "base64", $dispo = "attachment", $type = "application/octet-stream") {
        $file_str = $this->get_file_data($file);
        if ($file_str == "") {
            return;
        } else {
            if ($encoding == "base64") $file_str = base64_encode($file_str);
            $this->att_files[] = array(
                "data"=>chunk_split($file_str),
                "name"=>basename($file), 
                "cont_type"=>$type, 
                "trans_enc"=>$encoding,
                "disposition"=>$dispo);

        }
    }

    function add_html_image($img_name) {
        $file_str = $this->get_file_data($img_name);
        $img_dim = getimagesize($img_name);
        if ($file_str == "") {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->html_images[] = array(
                "data"=>chunk_split(base64_encode($file_str)),
                "name"=>basename($img_name), 
                "cont_type"=>$img_dim['mime'],
                "cid"=>md5(uniqid(time()))."@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        }
    }

    function create_stand_headers() {
        if ($this->from_name != "") {
            $headers = "From: ".$this->from_name." <".$this->from_mail.">".LIBR;
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$this->from_name." <".$this->from_mail.">".LIBR;
        } else {
            $headers = "From: ".$this->from_mail.LIBR;
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$this->from_mail.LIBR;
        }
        if ($this->mail_cc != "") $headers .= "Cc: ".$this->mail_cc.LIBR;
        if ($this->mail_bcc != "") $headers .= "Bcc: ".$this->mail_bcc.LIBR;
        $headers .= sprintf("Message-ID: <%s@%s>%s", md5(uniqid(time())), $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], LIBR);
        $headers .= "X-Priority: ".PRIORITY.LIBR;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: Attachment Mailer [version 1.2]".LIBR;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".LIBR;
        return $headers;
    }

    function create_html_image($img_array) {
        $img = "Content-Type: ".$img_array['cont_type'].";".LIBR.chr(9)." name=\"".$img_array['name']."\"".LIBR;
        $img .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".LIBR;
        $img .= "Content-ID: <image".$img_array['cid'].">".LIBR;
        $img .= "Content-Disposition: inline;".LIBR.chr(9)." filename=\"".$img_array['name']."\"".LIBR.LIBR;
        $img .= $img_array['data'];
        return $img;        
    }

    function create_attachment($data_array) {
        $att = "Content-Type: ".$data_array['cont_type'].";".LIBR.chr(9)." name=\"".$data_array['name']."\"".LIBR;
        $att .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: ".$data_array['trans_enc'].LIBR;
        $att .= "Content-Disposition: ".$data_array['disposition'].";".LIBR.chr(9)." filename=\"".$data_array['name']."\"".LIBR.LIBR;
        $att .= $data_array['data'];
        return $att;        
    }

    function create_html_body() {
        $html = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=".ENCODING.LIBR;
        $html .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: ".TRANS_ENC.LIBR.LIBR;
        foreach ($this->html_images as $img) {
            $this->html_body = str_replace($img['name'], "cid:image".$img['cid'], $this->html_body);
        }
        $html .= $this->html_body;
        return $html.LIBR.LIBR;
    }

    function build_message() {
        $this->headers = $this->create_stand_headers();
        $msg = "";
        $is_html = ($this->html_body != "") ? true : false;
        $is_attachment = (count($this->att_files) > 0) ? true : false;
        $is_images = (count($this->html_images) > 0) ? true : false;
        if ($is_attachment) {
            $this->uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
            $this->headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".LIBR.chr(9)." boundary=\"".$this->uid."\"".LIBR.LIBR;
            $this->headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.".LIBR;
            if (!$is_html) {
                $msg .= "--".$this->uid.LIBR;
            } else {
                $this->headers .= "--".$this->uid.LIBR;
            }
        } 
        if ($is_html) {
            $this->alternative_uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
            $this->headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".LIBR.chr(9)." boundary=\"".$this->alternative_uid."\"".LIBR.LIBR;
            if (!$is_attachment) {
                $this->headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.".LIBR;
            }
            $msg .= LIBR."--".$this->alternative_uid.LIBR;
        }
        $body_head = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=".ENCODING."; format=flowed".LIBR;
        $body_head .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: ".TRANS_ENC.LIBR.LIBR;
        if (!$is_attachment && !$is_html) {
            $this->headers .= $body_head;
        } else {
            $msg .= $body_head;
        }
        $msg .= trim($this->text_body).LIBR.LIBR;
        if ($is_html) {
            $msg .= "--".$this->alternative_uid.LIBR;
            if ($is_images) {
                $this->related_uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
                $msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/related;".LIBR.chr(9)." boundary=\"".$this->related_uid."\"".LIBR.LIBR.LIBR;
                $msg .= "--".$this->related_uid.LIBR;
                $msg .= $this->create_html_body();
                foreach ($this->html_images as $img) {
                    $msg .= "--".$this->related_uid.LIBR;
                    $msg .= $this->create_html_image($img);
                }
                $msg .= LIBR."--".$this->related_uid."--";
            } else {
                $msg .= $this->create_html_body();
            }
            $msg .= LIBR.LIBR."--".$this->alternative_uid."--".LIBR.LIBR;
        }
        if ($is_attachment) {
            foreach ($this->att_files as $att) {
                $msg .= "--".$this->uid.LIBR;
                $msg .= $this->create_attachment($att);
            }
            $msg .= "--".$this->uid."--";
        }
        return $msg;        
    }

    function process_mail() {
        if (!$this->valid_mail_adresses) return;
        if (mail($this->mail_to, $this->mail_subject, $this->build_message(), $this->headers, "-f".$this->webmaster_email)) {
            $this->msg[] = "Your mail is succesfully submitted.";
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->msg[] = "Error while sending you mail.";
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$test = new attach_mailer($name = "Olaf", $from = "youremail@gmail.com", $to = "toemail@gmail.com", $cc = "", $bcc = "", $subject = "Test text email with attachments");
$test->text_body = "...Some body text\n\n the admin";
$test->add_attach_file("uploads/admin_doc.docx");
//$test->add_attach_file("ip2nation.zip"); 
$test->process_mail();
echo $test->get_msg_str();
```