# How to send mail in php with attachement using php mail()

Tags: php

I have got error like 'PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header'

I was written like-

```
$message="<html><body>";
$message.= "<table width='100%' border='0'><tr><td>Dear</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Thanks for the Enquiry</td></tr>";  
$message.="</table></body></html>";
$header = "From: $email_from\r\n";
$header .= "CC:sales@arrowpackers.co.in\n";
$header .= "Reply-To:sales@arrowpackers.co.in\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileatt_name."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$fileatt_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
$ok=mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887610/error-with-php-mail-multiple-or-malformed-newlines-found-in-additional-header

Comment: Try Using \\\n instead of \n.

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail